# Python optimization of 3D grid search with nested loops

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization

Imagine we have a 3D grid with discrete points. The ranges for the 3 dimensions (interval endpoints included) are:

in x: [4000, 7000], stepsize 1000   in y: [0.0, 2.0], stepsize 1.0   in z: [-0.75, 0.75], stepsize 0.25

The task below should now be done for all points in the range [4000, 7000, 100], [0.0, 2.0, 0.1], [-0.75, 0.75, 0.05] (roughly 20000 = 31 * 21 * 31 points):

Find the smallest cuboid that contains the point. However there are holes in the grid (each point should have a "physical" counterpart as a file, but some do not). I tried the following really simple code (where I called cuboid 'cube'):

```
def findcubesnew(startvalues, endvalues, resols, \
  loopvalues, refvalues, modelpath):

  cubearray = []
  startvalue1 = startvalues[0]
  endvalue1 = endvalues[0]
  resol1 = resols[0]
  refvalue1 = refvalues[0]
  loopstop1 = loopvalues[0][0]
  loopstart1 = loopvalues[1][0]
  startvalue2 = startvalues[1]
  endvalue2 = endvalues[1]
  resol2 = resols[1]
  refvalue2 = refvalues[1]
  loopstop2 = loopvalues[0][1]
  loopstart2 = loopvalues[1][1]
  startvalue3 = startvalues[2]
  endvalue3 = endvalues[2]
  resol3 = resols[2]
  refvalue3 = refvalues[2]
  loopstop3 = loopvalues[0][2]
  loopstart3 = loopvalues[1][2]
  refmass = refvalues[3]
  refveloc = refvalues[4]

  for start1 in numpy.arange(startvalue1, loopstop1 + resol1, resol1):
    for end1 in numpy.arange(loopstart1, endvalue1 + resol1, resol1):
      for start2 in numpy.arange(startvalue2, loopstop2 + resol2, resol2):
        for end2 in numpy.arange(loopstart2, endvalue2 + resol2, resol2):
          for start3 in numpy.arange(startvalue3, loopstop3 + resol3, resol3):
            for end3 in numpy.arange(loopstart3, endvalue3 + resol3, resol3):
              if glob.glob(*start1*start2*start3) and \
                if glob.glob(modelpath/*start1*start2*end3) and \
                if glob.glob(modelpath/*start1*end2*start3) and \
                if glob.glob(modelpath/*start1*end2*end3) and \
                if glob.glob(modelpath/*end1*start2*start3) and \
                if glob.glob(modelpath/*end1*start2*end3) and \
                if glob.glob(modelpath/*end1*end2*start3) and \
                if glob.glob(modelpath/*end1*end2*end3):
                  cubearray.append((start1, end1, start2, end2, start3, end3))
                else:
                  pass
  return cubearray

foundcubearray = findcubesnew([metalstart, tempstart, loggstart], \
  [metalend, tempend, loggend], [metalresol, tempresol, loggresol], \
  looplimitarray, [refmetal, reftemp, reflogg, refmass, refveloc], \
  modelpath)
if foundcubearray:
  bestcube = findsmallestcubenew(foundcubearray, \
    [metalresol, tempresol, loggresol])
  ....
```

Hence I go in a loop in x direction from the lower grid border to the biggest value below the desired point where we want to get the cuboid, and in another loop from the smallest value after the point to the higher grid border. Similarly for the y- and the z-direction and the loops are nested one in each other. The if part is pseudocode without the format strings etc. and checks that all file with these values (and other quantities may be as well in the filename) does exist (that all corners of the cuboid are present).

This code also finds points or lines or rectangles if one or multiple coordinates of the point coincide with values in our grid, but it's not a problem (and actually desired).

The bottleneck here is that the search for the cuboids takes quite some time (the smallest cuboid can be found easily and quickly then, if there are multiple with the same (smallest) size I do not care which one to choose). Also I need to read in the start and end values of the grid, the stepsizes, the reference values (coordinates) of my point and some other variables. Any way to optimize the code? It takes roughly 1.4 sec per point so ~ 8 hours for the ~ 20000 points and this is too long.

I know that if I found the smallest cuboid e.g. for the point 4500, 0.5, 0.1, I can immediately tell that all other points inside the cube with limits [4000, 5000; 0.0, 1.0; 0, 0.25]  have the same smallest cuboid. Still I'm interested in a solution that optimizes the computation time for all 20000 runs. The application of this is an interpolation routine for stellar models where 8 grid points with a cuboid shape around the interpolation point are required.

P.S.: I hope that the continuation line breaks and indents are correct. In my code they do not exist, although it's not a good style to go beyond 80 chars per line :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is not to use glob. If I'm reading the numbers right, the modelpath directory could contain up to 20,000 files, and there might be 8 globs on these in the inner loop body. I'm surprised it only takes 1.4 seconds per point!

The file names are just being used as booleans, right? All that matters is whether the file exists or not.

I would create a 3D array of booleans with the same dimensions as your 3D grid, initialised to False. Then read through the contents of the directory, converting each filename into a 3D index and set that to True.

Then do your search over the points using the array of booleans, not the file system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it is true that it's not the for-loops that slow the program down but the if-clauses... deactivating the 8-fold if-clause but still appending the coordinates results in ~ 4 sec for 20000 models. I will try what you suggested, creating the array with numpy.zeros((4,3,7)) and globbing once the (84) models from all 20000 files, reading the filename "values", converting them into array indices and setting the resp. array value to 1.

Comment: Problem solved, it was the globbing :) Question has been marked as answered... thanks, again